# how to use sweet alert just before exporting excel file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to use sweet alert library to add a dialog box just before downloading my excel file

```html
  <button onclick="downloadExcel()" id="download" class="tab-group"  > Download</button>
```

then my Javascript function is as such

```js
    <script>
  function s2ab(s) {
    let buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length); //convert s to arrayBuffer
    let view = new Uint8Array(buf);  //create uint8array as viewer
    for (let i=0; i<s.length; i++) view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF; //convert to octet
    return buf;
  }
  function downloadExcel() {
    // notifications part  
    Swal.fire({
    title: 'success!',
    text: 'Do you want to continue',
    icon: 'success',
    timer: 3000 , 
    confirmButtonText: 'OK' 
    })

    // generate excel part
    let wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    wb.Props = {
      Title: "excel",
      Subject: "excel",
      Author: "aaa",
      CreatedDate: new Date()
    };
    wb.SheetNames.push("excel");
    const column1 = document.getElementById('column1').value;
    const column2 = document.getElementById('column2').value;
    let ws_data = [['key', 'value'], ['column1', column1], ['type', 'excel'], ['column2', column2]];
    let ws = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(ws_data);
    wb.Sheets["excel"] = ws;
    let wbout = XLSX.write(wb, {bookType:'xlsx',  type: 'binary'});

    saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)],{type:"application/octet-stream"}), 'excel.xlsx');
    
  }
</script>
```

my problem is that when i run my button it automaticly download the excel and the dialog box just show and hide without letting me click ok button in the dialog box .

how can i achieve this scenario
***(click download button --> dialog box show -->click ok in the dialog box --> excel will be downloaded ? )?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use confirm like:

```
function s2ab(s) {
  let buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length); //convert s to arrayBuffer
  let view = new Uint8Array(buf); //create uint8array as viewer
  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF; //convert to octet
  return buf;
}

function downloadExcel() {
  // notifications part  
  Swal.fire({
    title: 'Do you want to continue?',
    icon: 'success',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes!'
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.isConfirmed) {
      let wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
      wb.Props = {
        Title: "excel",
        Subject: "excel",
        Author: "aaa",
        CreatedDate: new Date()
      };
      wb.SheetNames.push("excel");
      const column1 = document.getElementById('column1').value;
      const column2 = document.getElementById('column2').value;
      let ws_data = [
        ['key', 'value'],
        ['column1', column1],
        ['type', 'excel'],
        ['column2', column2]
      ];
      let ws = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(ws_data);
      wb.Sheets["excel"] = ws;
      let wbout = XLSX.write(wb, {
        bookType: 'xlsx',
        type: 'binary'
      });

      saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)], {
        type: "application/octet-stream"
      }), 'excel.xlsx');

    } else if (
      result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel
    ) {
      Swal.fire(
        'Abort download',
        'Download stopped!',
        'error'
      );
    }
  });


}
```

With `.then((result)` you can catch if user press ok or not, then choise the action, for example if user abort, another messagge will display.

Example work here (without excel download):

```js
downloadExcel();
function downloadExcel() {
  // notifications part  
  Swal.fire({
    title: 'Do you want to continue?',
    icon: 'success',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes!'
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.isConfirmed) {
      console.log('download excel');
    } else if (
      result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel
    ) {
      Swal.fire(
        'Abort download',
        'Download stopped!',
        'error'
      );
    }
  });


}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

---

Last advice, please don't use inline call function, instead use `addEventListener`

Comment: Hello thanks for your code ! but there is a problem that i'm facing is that when the dialog box show it disspears suddenly just after few seconds is it because my navigator (using chrome)

Comment: the page refresh just when i click the download but

Comment: I don't understand, the only possibility is if you click on black background on open popup it will close and what do you mean by page refresh???? Because you didn't metioned that to your question